# Spring Boot logout

Tags: spring-boot

I am facing issue with spring boot logout..

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
    .permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

I have added this code in my WebSecurityConfig class.

It simply refeshes the page and comes back to home page(page redirect logic present in angular JS code)

I tried this also

```java
 http.logout()
         .logoutUrl("/logout")
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
         .invalidateHttpSession( true )
         .deleteCookies("CSISESSION");
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: What do `"/"` map to in your application? Do you have a welcome-file configured?

Comment: Your redirect doesn't work or spring logout? 
Can you check with this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii)? Maybe it's something with your angular controller logic.

Comment: Thanks..found the fix..it was the return URL issue since its a SSO based.